# Rough-in Inspection of Existing/New Circuit Breaker

Tags: electrical

I have an existing Circuit in my unfinished basement for light fixture. I am rewiring currently.
After rewiring for light fixtures, I am putting switches for each wherever possible, to make sure everything is went right after I turned the power ON.  I am not installing receptible for now.

So I have questions

1. Is this Ok to leave the switches there for existing breaker when electric inspection comes ?
   I'll have to take them out before drywall
2. For new Circuit breaker, All new breaker should be in placed/connected in Panel before inspection, and should be turned off, right ?

Thanks in Advance !!

Comment: What is being inspected? The rough inspection will need all the wiring, conduit/ boxes to be in place. Are you expecting multiple rough inspections? Where in the world are you jurisdiction matters in some cases.

Comment: inspecting rough-in for rewiring, outlets, switchbox, breakers in basement, so I think everything.

Comment: Remember to use /3 cable for switch loops! Most of the pages on the web will say /2 is OK, that is obsolete, they changed it 10 years ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a rough inspection the inspector needs all the physical wiring and clamps to be in place.
Since your switches are on an existing circuit and live they need to be in the boxes they can be pulled and angled to put the Sheetrock up later.

Make sure you have 6+ inches wire in the boxes,
Make sure at least 1/4” of the nmb or Romex outer sheath is inside the box.
Make sure you staple the wiring 8-12” from the box (8” if no clamps).
Make sure any cable that is through a hole is 1-1/4” back from the stud face
If stapling make sure cable is stapled 1-1/4” back from face(s) of studs.
These are the things my local inspectors check on a rough inspection.

Depending on your version of code (you did not provide location) you may need a neutral in the switch boxes.

Comment: Thanks Ed Beal for the details. One thing you mentioned "cable is stapled 1-1/4” back from face(s) of studs".  Actually in 3 gang box, I have stapled separately each wire for each switch side by side than stacking them under one staple.  so I am seeing wire stapled 1 or 3/4 inch back from face of stud. So I'll have to fix this. Thanks for putting everything together.

Comment: Don’t go more than 2 cables under 1 staple unless you get a cable staple stacker rated for more.

Comment: Does pigtail wire in the box needs to be 6+ as well or little shorter will also work ?

Comment: A pig tail is a group of wires that are connected then another piece of wire is connected (the pig tail) the wires from the back of the box shall be 6” minimum the pig tail is not regulated by code but some internet electricians state it is but do not understand what a pig tail is. 310.14 states the length of the wire from the back of the box. If you had several 6” long pig tails the inspector may cite you for excessive wire in the box. I have seen that. But there is no minimum length of the pig tail itself just the wires spliced in the box. So yes shorter is ok and even needed in some cases.